# ¿Cómo puedo renderizar un componente x veces?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

Soy nuevo en React Native y no sé como puedo renderizar un componente varias veces, digamos que tengo un componente que es una caja, yo quiero que me renderize ese componente 9 veces por ejemplo.

Este es el componente que me da una caja, le he quitado los styles para no liar más.

```
class Box extends Component<Props> {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <View>
                    <Text></Text>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <Text></Text>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <Text></Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Y llamo al componente anterior desde este otro componente:

```
class Prov extends Component<MyProps, MyState> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            componentController: true}
    }
    changeStateTrue() {
       this.setState({componentController: true});
    }

    changeStateFalse() {
        this.setState({componentController: false});
    }

    render() {
        let renderComponent;
        const componentController = this.state.componentController;

        if (componentController) {
            renderComponent=<Box/>
        }

        return (
            <View>
                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.changeStateTrue()}>
                        <Text> Por Aceptar  </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.changeStateFalse()}>
                        <Text> En curso </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <View>
                    {renderComponent}
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Pues simplemente lo llamas 9 veces.

```
<Box />
<Box />
<Box />   
<Box />
<Box />
<Box />
<Box />
<Box />
<Box />
```

Acuérdate de importarlo. Por ejemplo...

```
import Box from '../src/components/Box'
```

y que el fichero se llame Box.js

También puedes meterlo en un bucle for, etc.

Comment: Creo que no me he explicado bien, lo que yo intento es que el componente se renderize en un bucle, ya sean nueve veces o veinte.

Answer (score 0):

Pues en ese caso:

```
for (let step = 0; step < 10; step++) {
    <Box />
}
```

Comment: probablemente sea mejor editar tu publicación anterior y añadir esta referencia, en lugar de añadir una nueva respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Otra manera es:

```
var boxes = []
for(var i=0; i<9; i++) boxes.push(<Box key={`box-${i}`} />)
return (<div>
         .....
         {boxes}
         ....
        </div>)
```

Nota: al crear un arreglo de elementos, usualmente react necesitara una llave para identificar a cada uno (si no se coloca, veras alertas en la consola)